# CMake add_subdirectory causes CPack to build only source directory

Tags: cmake

I'm piloting cmake 3.11 for my team.  Among the things I wish to demonstrate is prototypes for managing our internal/external dependencies.  I must also distribute our suite of executables and libraries to customers who may or may not have internet connectivity, and who may or may not have the ability to reach our repository.

At present, I have developed templates to be used with all internal projects that have the following situations:

**FetchContent from Repository to get Local Network Dependency**

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    internaldependency
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@repo.net:ProductFamily/Project.git
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(internaldependency)
if(NOT internaldependency_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(internaldependency)
    add_subdirectory(${internalproject_SOURCE_DIR} ${internalproject_BINARY_DIR} )
```

This is the template I've developed for all projects to export for install/cpack, ideally so that customers could include libraries in our product family with anything they may develop:

```
include(CPack)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "TGZ")
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ourlibrary EXPORT ourlibrary_export
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(EXPORT  ourlibrary_export
    FILE ourlibraryTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE productfamily
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfigVersion.cmake
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)
configure_package_config_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CMake/ourlibraryConfig.cmake.in # It's a package init and an inclusion to ourlibraryTargets.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfig.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfigVersion.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfig.cmake
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
install(DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/etc/ourlibrary
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR}
)
```

Given a situation where I have `MainLibrary` and `DependencyLibrary`, both of which include the above install target template in their build scripts: If `MainLibrary` includes `DependencyLibrary` by way of `FetchContent`+`add_subdirectory`, cpack always archives the source directory as a source distribution, when I only ever want it to produce a release distribution based on the install targets.  Install behaves as desired, and cpack would also behave as desired if I use `find_packages` to get `DependencyLibrary` included in main, but `add_subdirectories` causes CPack to only ever want to archive the source directory.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: It doesn't seem that `DependencyLibrary` installs any files or at least the CMakeLists.txt shown only show files being installed for the main library.  You might want to check that when building `DependencyLibrary` by itself that it's install targets are working properly.

Comment: The install targets are the same template used in the CMakeLists or both libraries, substitute `ourlibrary` in that template with `DependencyLibrary` or `MainLibrary` as needed.

Comment: CPack packs everything given in `install()` commands. If you include other project via `add_subdirectory`, and this project contains `install()` commands, these commands will be processed by CPack when it is applied to the main project. Approach `find_package` processes `XXXConfig.cmake` scripts, which don't contain `install()` commands, so CPack takes nothing from the subprojects, included in such way.

Comment: Neither project has listed the source project directory as an install target, as shown in the template reused across both projects, so why would cpack try to pack it in the `add_subdirectory` case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was the location of `include(CPack)`.  Since the statement is in itself responsible for generating the CPack configurations, calling it as early as I did generated those configurations before I had defined everything necessary for them.

The template for setting up install targets has changed as follows:

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ourlibrary EXPORT ourlibrary_export
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(EXPORT  ourlibrary_export
    FILE ourlibraryTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE productfamily
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfigVersion.cmake
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)
configure_package_config_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CMake/ourlibraryConfig.cmake.in # It's a package init and an inclusion to ourlibraryTargets.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfig.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
install(FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfigVersion.cmake
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ourlibraryConfig.cmake
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/ourlibrary
)
install(DIRECTORY
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/etc/ourlibrary
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR}
)
include(CPack)
```

By moving the include until after the install targets were defined, my problem was resolved.